# Precision of a power of double in bison and avr-g++

Tags: c++, double, bison, avr, pow

I am writing a calculator for an `avr` microcontroller using `bison` and I have a problem with the resolution of a power of 2 doubles.

In my `bison` file I define the type as

```
    %define api.value.type {double}
    %token NUMBER
```

and then give the following rule

```
expr: NUMBER
     | expr '^' expr {$$ = pow($1, $3);}
```

And the code works properly except when I try to calculate `2^8` that gives me `255.9999`as the answer instead of `256`.

To see if the problem is with `double`or with `pow` I have modified the code this way:

```
expr: NUMBER
     | expr '^' expr {$$ = pow($1, $3);
                      double a = 2.0; double b = 8.0;
                      if (a == $1) lcd << "a ok";  // prints ok
                      if (b == $3) lcd << "b ok";  // prints ok
                      double c = pow(a, b);
                      lcd << c; // it shows 256!!!
                      if ($$ == c) lcd << "$$ ok";
                      else         lcd << "$$ wrong"; // prints wrong!!!!
                     }
```

As you can see the function `pow` works ok with `a` and `b`, and these two variables have the same value that `$1` and `$3` but `$$` is different from `c = pow(a, b)`.

I don't know what is happening.

Its the first time I use `bison` so most probably I've done something wrong.

I am compiling with avr-g++ 9.2.0.

Thanks.

---

Edit:
To see what is happening I've modified my rule in two different ways:

If I try:

```
expr: NUMBER
     | expr '^' expr {yyval = pow(2.0, 8.0);}
```

it gives me the right answer and print `256`.

But instead if I try:

```
expr: NUMBER
     | expr '^' expr {yyval = pow($1, $3);}
```

it gives me the wrong answer `255.9999`

Comment: I recommend writing a simple program that outputs `(2.0 << 8)`.  See what happens (you may want to use `set_precision` with a high value like 15.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `(2.0 << 8)` doesn't compile in C++. `2.0` is a `double` and `8` an `int`. Also I can't use `set_precision` because I'm programming a microcontroller (and don't have implement `set_precision`). I tested all the code in my PC using `set_precision` and it works fine, and also test it in other programs in the microcontroller and also works fine.

Comment: I just found out that G++ doesn't like `(2.0 << 8)` or `(2.0 << 8.0)`.

Comment: @thomas: `<<` is a bitwise left shift, which is not a meaningful operation on floating point numbers. The C and C++ standards insist that both arguments of `<<` and `>>` be integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with bison. The culprit is the math library on the AVR microcontroller.

When you write (in C):

```
double a = 2.0;
double b = 8.0;
double c = pow(a, b);
```

Gcc is smart enough to figure out that c will be 256.0. it's not necessary to do that computation at run time. Gcc just rewrites that to `double c = 256.0;`.

Gcc does that computation using the math library on the machine it is running on, or with its own bundled math library. That's likely to be the Gnu math library, which optimises the computation of small integer powers.

The other call to `pow` is computed at runtime, because the compiler can't know what `$1` and `$3` are going to be. So that call is done with the math library on the microcontroller, which is very slightly inaccurate. (It might do something like `exp(8.0 * log(2.0))`, which introduces a small round-off error.)

One possible solution would be to write your own implementation of `pow`, which uses a more precise computation when the exponent is an integer.

Comment: Yes, it seems that's the answer. If I change `double a = 2.0` and `double b = 8.0` by `volatile double a = 2.0` and `volatile double b = 8.0` the `pow(a,b)` gives the wrong answer `255.999`. Thanks.

Comment: @antonio: looking at the disassembly of the bison action would probably also have been revealing.

Answer (score 0):

avr-gcc double is 32 bits per default. For 64-bit double you'll need avr-gcc v10+, cf. the GCC release notes

https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html#avr

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Libf7

The rounding and precision issues inherent to floating-point numbers will still be there, though.